# need hyphen instead of zero in my excel formula

Tags: excel

I want to add some values in my excel sheet , but when there is no value want hyphen instead of zero .

Here is my formula as below : 
=IFERROR(SUMIF(A1:A6,"="&VLOOKUP($F$3,A1:B6,1,FALSE),B1:B6),"-")

Answer (score 1):

The formula for that'd be:

`=IFERROR(IF(SUMIF(A1:A6,"="&VLOOKUP($F$3,A1:B6,1,FALSE),B1:B6)=0,"-",SUMIF(A1:A6,"="&VLOOKUP($F$3,A1:B6,1,FALSE),B1:B6)),"-")`

But I suspect you just want to change the number format to ACCOUNTING... it automatically replaces zeros with hyphens.